# Why this Python "loop code" does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, variables, repeat

Why this code does not work?

```py
ffi5_1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/d/bm_ffi5_1.csv')
ffi5_2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/d/bm_ffi5_2.csv')
ffi5_3 = pd.read_csv('/Users/d/bm_ffi5_3.csv')
ffi5_4 = pd.read_csv('/Users/d/bm_ffi5_4.csv')
ffi5_5 = pd.read_csv('/Users/d/bm_ffi5_5.csv')

s_list = list(range(1,6))

for x in s_list:
    ffi5_x.jdate = pd.to_datetime(ffi5_x.jdate)
```

Here jdate is the column of dataframe.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: You need to add what you want to do, what was your thought process behind what you tried. And this code lacks basic syntax, I would suggest you to study basic python coding and syntax before trying something exotic.

Comment: where is the body of the loop?

Comment: Well, trivially because you have an indentation error, and `ffi5_x` is not defined.

Comment: guys thanks for all commenting. This was my first question with clumsy. Plz understand it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably fails with a message that you attempt to refer to
a non-existing variable *ffi5_x*.

In order to replace *x* in the DataFrame name with the current value
of *x* - loop control variable (in 2 places), change your loop to:

```
for x in s_list:
    exec('ffi5_' + str(x) + '.jdate = pd.to_datetime(ffi5_' + str(x) + '.jdate)')
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much!